# How can I add graphic elements in android using code?

Tags: android, graphics, element

How can I add graphic elements in android without the use of drag it into main.xml?
I mean using code to make them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at this tutorial for starters: [create Android UI in Java code](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/48845.aspx)